# Is it possible to test PhoneGap applications using MonkeyTalk?

Tags: testing, cordova

After reading monkeytalk faq from http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation/monkeytalk-faq :

**How does it all work?**

MonkeyTalk is a complete functional testing platform for mobile applications. Currently, it supports testing native iOS and Android apps.

**Can I test HTML5 web apps?**

No. Our initial release of MonkeyTalk comes with an iOS Agent and an Android Agent. That being said, we understand the importance of HTML5 apps, particularly in the mobile space. So don’t be surprised if you see an HTML5 Agent some time in the future.

**Can I test desktop apps? Windows Phone 7? BlackBerry? Flex Mobile?**

No. Our initial release of MonkeyTalk comes with a native iOS Agent and a native Android Agent. That being said, we hope to add more agents in the future.

... I am not really sure I can use monkeytalk to test phonegap applications. Does anyone have any experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the Gorilla Logic guys at the last AnDevCon and they had just cracked the ability to test a WebView inside of a native app. Sadly they could not record a test script but they can play back a manually created script. You may want to talk to Gorilla Logic directly.